# react router switch route doesn't work gh-pages on github.io

Tags: reactjs, github

I've been having problems with deploying my react app on `github.io`

I always have my 404 page loaded whenever I start the link: `myname.github.io/myapp`

Then if I click on `/saved`, it redirects to the right **'saved'** page but if I click on any **'topic'** page, it loads the 404 page again with the url: `myname.github.io`

I've added: `gh-pages`, added scripts and run `npm run deploy` following this [instruction](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#github-pages).

I've also added `path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}` but nothing works.

Here's my `app.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Saved from './pages/Saved';
import Topic from './pages/Topic';
import Result from './pages/Result';
import NoMatch from './pages/NoMatch';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import './App.css';

const App = () =>
    <Router>
        <div>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'} component={Home} />
            <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/saved'} component={Saved} />
            <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/topic'} component={Topic} />
            <Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/result'} component={Result} />
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>;

export default App;
```

Update 6 Apr 2018

Adding project name to PUBLIC_URL solves the problem of 404 Homepage.

```
App.js
<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/g4g-debate/'} component={Home} />
```

However, all other links lead to 404 page. I've tried:

```
App.js
<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/g4g-debate/saved'} component={Saved} />
```

or

```
<Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/saved'} component={Saved} />
```

or

```
<Route exact path='/saved' component={Saved} />
```

On other pages:

```
<Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/g4g-debate/saved/'}>User Profile</Link>
```

or

```
<Link to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/saved'}>User Profile</Link>
```

or

```
<Link to='/saved'>User Profile</Link>
```

You can take a look at it here: https://vnndi.github.io/g4g-debate/

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you have `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`? You shouldn't need that... The routes should be relative. Anyway, what is the value of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` to prefix each route path. The route paths should be relative. I would suggest you remove that.

You did not specify what the value of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is in your question, but I can guess it is `myname.github.io`?

In any case, the problem you have is because the app is at `https://vnndi.github.io/g4g-debate/`, but when you click the `User Profile` link, it goes to `https://vnndi.github.io/saved`. That route does not match. It should be the following:

https://vnndi.github.io/g4g-debate/saved

So to fix the problem remove the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` prefix and just use:

```
<Route exact path="/saved" component={Saved} />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I originally had <Route exact path="/saved" component={Saved} /> but it didn't work so I looked for answers and some people suggest using that. Also, even removing the PUBLIC_URL, it doesn't help with the 404 when I first click the link to my app. It's not just the 'saved' page only.

Comment: @Viet could you try using HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter and let me know if it works? (1) If it does work, then there might be something to do with load balancing, GitHub not allowing you to have routes without a `#`. (2) In that case, you can fix the problem appending `/g4g-debate` to your current definition of `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` (btw, please tell us what the value of that variable is). I don't think it's a good solution, but it should work.

Comment: I looked here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md but it doesn't make much sense to me how to use HashRouter. Also, I looked but couldn't find how to retrieve the value of process.env.PUBLIC_URL

Comment: Also, with the old code (without PUBLIC_URL), I was able to deploy it on heroku, but not on github.io. If you could help me with deploying my app on github.io, that'd be great.

Comment: many thanks. Route exact path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/g4g-debate/'} component={Home} /> gets me to the home page. However, all links lead to my 404 page. I've updated my question above.

Comment: @Viet okay, your Link contains `to={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/saved'}`. Please remove that, and only have it like `to="/saved"`. Then, remove that also from the Route: `<Route exact path="/saved" component={Saved} />`

Comment: @Viet Replace BrowserRouter with HashRouter and tell me whether it works. It should work.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The homepage loads as expected but all the other links lead to 404 page. Thank you so much for your help @nbkhope but I have to scratch this project and move on. We've spent too much time on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and you said you abandoned it, but these for those who are curious:

`react-router-dom` supports setting a basename on the router object:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={'/g4g-debate'}>
  <Stuff />
</BrowserRouter>
```

This will automatically set all `<Link />`'s and `<Route />`'s to use the basepath at the start of the path, and then you no longer need to include `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` manually.

As far as the 404 error you were getting, that might also be due to the settings on the github page. I can't speak to github specifically, but a lot of hosting services have a way to set an 'error' page, which is what it will server when the path doesn't correspond to something that doesn't exist. In a one page app with only virtual paths, you need to set the error page to your root `index.html` file, so that it will server the page and then `react-router` will handle the actual route.